# Unknown class SavedQuotesViewController in Interface Builder file in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have changed the class name in my project but after building app shows Unknown class SavedQuotesViewController in Interface Builder file.

Please help on this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did You change name here....in .h file @interface changedclassname and in .m file

```
#import "changedclassname.h"
@implementation changedclassname
```

Hope, this will help you...